# Are the waves on survival completely endless?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I'm wondering if there is a limit to the number of waves in MW3's survival mode. I found this spot in terminal where if you sit cozily, you cant be shot at but you can shoot everyone else. After about an hour I reached wave 60 but made a mistake and died.

So is there be a limit? Is there an end situation like "you won, help has arrived"?

Comment: I want this location. EDIT: according to the wiki, there is no end. I think that sounds right. http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_Mode

Comment: Without seeing the code, you can't prove, only disprove the infinity of waves.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in my comment, the Call of Duty wikia says that the waves are endless. I also thought that would be the case because that is normally what "survival mode" means.

[Survival Mode - The Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_Mode)

I was going to leave only a comment, but then I tried to search for the hiding spot you mentioned and I found some videos of people getting to much higher waves, like this one ending on wave 225 and calling it a world record:

While this doesn't prove that there isn't a secret ending at some point, it probably does prove that you would get bored and want to quit long before you reach it.

Also, in theory the waves will stop increasing once the number of waves reaches or exceeds the largest integer supported by the system's processor. This would probably require more than a year of constant gameplay even on a 32-bit system, but it's an interesting note to add.

Answer (score -1):

The waves are never ending , they just get harder and harder and eventually you will
Die. But if you watch youtube videos you can survive for longer

Comment: Hi Kentucky,While this answer is presumably correct, it does not appear to add anything to the other answers. But welcome to Arqade!

Answer (score -2):

I really can't remember how long it took or what round we finally made it to finish but actually whenever you get so far it just restarted to round one again with a little denotion of 1. Like 1¹…2¹and so on.